# jQuery use td value as src for img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to change to wrap a td value into an image using innerWrap,

```
jQuery( "td[id^='imageList']" ).wrapInner( "<img></img>" );
jQuery( "td[id^='imageList']" ).wrapInner( "<img>" );
jQuery( "td[id^='imageList']" ).wrapInner( "<img src=''>" );
```

which (obviously) all failed.

```
http://source.to/image.png
```

becomes

```
<img>http://source.to/image.png</img>
```

What I want is

```
http://source.to/image.png
```

to become

```
<img src="http://source.to/image.png">
```

Anybody has a good idea to solve this problem?

Comment: do you want the `src` attribute to be picked up from the `<td>` somehow?

Comment: Can you show us your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an image and change the source. To do that, you can use :

```
jQuery( "td[id^='imageList']" ).each(function(){
    $this = jQuery(this);
    var img = jQuery('<img>', {'src' : $this.text()});
    $this.empty().append(img);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.wrapInner(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/#wrapInner-function)

Use

```
jQuery("td[id^='imageList']").wrapInner(function() {
  return "<img src='"+ $(this).text() +"'></img>";
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/nNRmL/)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
jQuery( "td[id^='imageList']" ).each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var src = jQuery.trim($this.text());
    $this.html('<img src="'+ src +'">');
});
```

Trimming the string is good as you might have some spaces around the path too.

Example: http://codepen.io/KATT/pen/dqJGA

Btw, I would probably use `class` rather than `id` for this.

Example #2: http://codepen.io/KATT/pen/AjvdK